# How to access field values/attrs in an inlineformset_factory?

Tags: django, django-forms

Sometimes browsers can render an empty label in a select box as `-----`:

[image]

In a `ModelForm` it's easy to fix this by replacing the `empty_label` attr as below:

```
class CustomModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Loop over the ModelForm fields to update field types and attributed
        for field_name in self.fields:
            field = self.fields[field_name]

            if hasattr(field, 'empty_label'):
                # Remove the first empty label '-----'
                field.empty_label = None
```

However, when using an `inlineformset_factory` how does one do similar? E.g.

```
MyFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Author,
    Book,
    fields=MYFIELDS,
    extra=0
)
```

Answer (score 1):

## try using formfield_callback keyword

```
def field_callback(db_field, **kwargs):
    form_field = db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
    if hasattr(form_field.widget, 'empty_label'):
        # Remove the first empty label '-----'
        form_field.widget.empty_label = None
    return form_field

MyFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Author,
    Book,
    fields=MYFIELDS,
    extra=0,
    formfield_callback = field_callback,
)
```